# How to set verbose name for django user defiend admin action

Tags: django, django-admin

As in django [documentation here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/), I wrote my first Django action like this:

```
def make_verified(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    query_set.update(title='new title')
```

It works pretty right. But I need to change the shown name for this action. currently, the name is shown as below:

[image: admin action shown picture]

It means the name of the function which handles the action of this choice.
I couldn't find anything about this in the documentation.

How can I set verbose for this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained in the documentation you link to:

> we can provide a better, more human-friendly name by giving the function a `short_description` attribute

So you can do this:

```
def make_verified(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    query_set.update(title='new title')
make_verified.short_description = 'Whatever description you like'
```